# Thumb detection Using Secugen's FDxSDKProAndroid.jar library

Tags: java, android, fingerprint

I have developed E-Attendance System using `Secugen's FDxSDKProAndroid.jar` library.

When user put his/her thumb on machine, machine automatically detect thumb and process it further. But issue is that if user do not move his thumb out of machine's screen then machine process again and again.

I have added a delay of 5 seconds of reprocessing but again its not a valid.

So I want a solution like once process is completed, library tell that still thumb has not moved out of screen, or just like a variable that return false if thumb has not moved away and return true if moved away.
Thanks in advance.

I can provide more information if required but please help me out.

Following is code snapshot that process when thumb is detected:

[image]

Comment: Please add code using code blocks and not images.

Comment: I can share secugen FDxSDKProAndroid.jar library, cause everything is all about that api library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a place in your API or in your code where there is a flag on auto capture. That may not be the case but if I were in your shoes I would  be forced to tie the event of fingerprint capture to only happen after the event of fingerpint removed has been fired when there is a fingerprint template that was extracted from a previous fingerprint capture.

I do not have access to your API so I won't be able to tell you exactly which method to call after the other but if I did I could explore its objects and tell you how to go about it.